# Write HTML tags for new line on cursor position

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

I placed cursor just after `lorem`and press `Enter`

By default, pressing `enter`, chrome writes here its own `span` tags.

```js
$("#test").keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var a = "<br>\n";
    /* here I need something like this:
    write - on - cursor - position(a); */

  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test" contenteditable="true">loremIpsum</div>
```

Comment: so on enter you want to insert new line break? What's happening actually?

Comment: Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, actually happens what I said  - `bu default chrome...`

Comment: @zer00ne, all relevant code is here - `html - js` plus description what happens and what I need. `jsfiddle` cannot show anything plus. css is absolutely irrelevant.

Comment: @bonaca *...CSS and HTML **that would be relevant** to your question.* Anyways, I edited your question and put your code in a snippet (took less than 2 minutes.) from there, I guessed at what you were asking (you made a statement which had no question mark "?") So I corrected your code so it complies with the behavior you have described. Hopefully that was what you wanted, let me know otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this property `e.preventDefault();` and the desired behavior will be enabled.

```js
$("#test").keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    /* e.preventDefault(); */
    var a = "<br>\n";

  };
});
```

```css
#test {
  height: 100px;
  width: 75%;
  padding:10px;
  margin: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test" contenteditable="true">loremIpsum</div>
```